# "Error: Too many re-renders" when trying to useState() for semantic-ui Dimmer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to make the dimmer show only on `ETH` or `Select a token` button clicks. I couldn't even get the state part working so I can connect the buttons.

```
function Main () {
  const [accountAddress, setAccountAddress] = useState(null);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

return (
    <div ref={contextRef}>
      <Dimmer.Dimmable as={Segment} dimmed={show}>
          <Grid style={styles.grid}>
            <Grid.Row>
              <Grid.Column>
                <Card style={styles.card} centered>
                  <Card.Content>
                    <Card.Header style={styles.padding}>Swap / Pool</Card.Header>
                      <Input style={styles.padding} fluid type='text' placeholder='0.0'>
                        <Label basic>From</Label>
                        <input />
                        <Button>ETH <Icon name='angle down' /></Button>
                      </Input>
                      <Input style={styles.padding} fluid type='text' placeholder='0.0'>
                        <Label basic>To</Label>
                        <input />
                        <Button>Select a Token <Icon name='angle down' /></Button>
                      </Input>
                      <Button style={styles.padding} color='teal' fluid size='large'>
                        Connect Wallet
                      </Button>
                  </Card.Content>
                </Card>
              </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
          </Grid>
        <Dimmer onClickOutside={setShow(false)}>
          <Header as='h2' icon inverted>
            <Icon name='heart' />
            Dimmed Message!
          </Header>
        </Dimmer>
      </Dimmer.Dimmable>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I removed a-lot of unrelated code but left in the other instance where I use `useState()` because I feel like that might be part of the issue.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Originally you were using as `<Dimmer onClickOutside={setShow(false)}>` in your code. In this way it gets into an infinite loop because on every render it gets called which triggers an another render.

You need to pass as a callback instead:

```
<Dimmer onClickOutside={() => setShow(false)}>
```

In this way `setShow(false)` will be called once `onClickOutside` event triggers.

Comment: I wrapped the `Dimmer` only around the `Header` tags and added `onClick={() => setShow(true)}` in the `ETH` button. The dimmer is still not showing up somehow